# rsort sorting order

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array which contains the following numbers:

```
10000
900
670
600
500
```

I want to sort the array in that format above. Largest to smallest, thus using rsort().
However the outcome turns out to be:

```
900
670
600
500
10000
```

Looks like rsort() just looks at the first digit of the whole number to sort the array. Is there any fix to this?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that the numbers are actually strings. The simplest thing to do would be to use the `SORT_NUMERIC` flag.

```
rsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling `rsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the SORT_NUMERIC flag.

```
rsort($myArray, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php